# How do I resolve interviewing where companies offer 10% less than I ask?

Tags: salary, job-offer, europe

I'm actively searching for a job right now and passed a decent amount of interviews. I ask *average salary in the market* and have several offers. The selection is not so big, but I revealed a rule: companies offer 10% less than I asked. For example, if I ask companyA for salary `x` per year, they offer about `0.9x` per year. Then companyB is asked for salary `1.1x` per year and they offer `x` per year. Ok, now I know how to be offered `x`.

But the question is: is that a game? What is the purpose of this game? How to handle this? That is a bit offensive.

P.S.: This happens in Europe and never happened in my homeland.

*Updated*: The deviation is not always 10%, it might be 6% or 8%. The difference seems not significant for a company.

Comment: Your sample size is what, three negotiations? Four? I can guarantee you that if you ask for a cool million you won't get a counter offer for 900K. That should tell you enough about the value of your "rule".

Comment: I am confused as to why you would find it offensive. It isn't meant personally, it is just business. They have a fiduciary responsibility to shareholders to hold down salary costs. So they offer less and see if you will take it. Many people will.

Comment: "If I ask companyA for salary x per year, they offer about 0.9x per year.". Is this where the negotations at company A ended? If you otherwise liked the offer, did you not try to get them back to x?

Comment: A good company would offer what they think you are worth to them, not what you asked for minus some percentage. If you genuinely asked for what you want, you tell them that you won't work for less - if they think you are not worth it, you won't get the job. If it was a lame negotiating tactics they will increase their offer and you learned something about the company.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to lack a little something when it comes to salary negotiations.

Some thing to keep in mind:

**1. How much they can pay**

The average developer salary in southern Ontario is, I'm told $75K. I can tell you right now that no one outside of Toronto (and a few special cases) is going to pay that much. The most you can hope to make outside of Toronto (for a non-senior) is maybe $60K - $65K as an intermediate dev with ***solid*** experience (5+ years).

In other words, if I live in Niagara and ask for $75K I would probably get exactly nowhere, as few employers in that area have that kind of budget.

Furthermore, even if "a lot" of Toronto companies offer $75K, not all of them do. Some will not value your skills as highly, while others will simply not have the budget.

**2. Negotiations**

The other biggie to keep in mind is that companies are like customers at an auction:

> ***They want the best talent for the least money.***

Many articles on the topic say that in a negotiation *the first person to name their salary range loses*. I agree with this assessment, but with the addendum that unless you're an experienced professional with a valuable skill set (for that company) your negotiation leverage is limited.

As an intermediate dev I still try to retain some control by not revealing how much I make, but rather what I ***want*** to make. This is how a typical conversation with a recruiter of HR rep will go:

> **HR:** In order for the process to move forward, we'd like to ask you a few more questions. How much do you currently make? 
>  **Me:** Well, I don't feel comfortable revealing that information to you at this time, however I can tell you that I'm interested in making between **$x** and **y$** (where **x** is what I want to make, and ***y*** is **x + $5000**) 
>  **HR:** Oh? I can guarantee you that whatever you tell me remains strictly confidential, and I'm afraid it's information I require for us to go forward. 
>  **Me:** My salary makes sense for my current position, responsibilities, and situation. In order to make the jump to your organization - something which interests me greatly - I feel that compensation within the range of **$x - $y** would be appropriate. If you disagree then I am sorry that we will have to part ways. If you however have a counter offer I am willing to hear you out.

If you tell them "I want $X" then they will immediately quote you a lower value because it's within their interest to do so.

Play your cards closer to your chest, and keep your interest in mind. If a company simply cannot give you what you ask they may be able to supplement the amount with a signing bonus, or by offering more vacation days, or other perks. You have to inquire and negotiate.

Comment: I've always shared my current salary, and I know they are using it to fuel their negotiations. I've definitely heard "you're looking to make a 10-15k jump?". And I've always been able to out negotiate them. Really it always came down to "You're looking for someone with my talent, you're willing to pay $X, and I can't accept anything under my range."

I think people are satisfied in the fact that they were able to try to negotiate you down, but if you withhold that chance from them in the very beginning you don't get very far.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan - I've read a lot of conflicting advice regarding salary negotiations. At the end of the day it all comes down to what works for you.

Comment: $75K CAD? Really? How do they keep all the developers from emigrating? Interns are getting like $6K USD/month in Seattle.

Answer (score 4):

If you see a pattern or trend, then factor it into your negotiations.

If everyone is offering 10% less than what you ask for, ask for 10% more initially.

There's many reasons why they might be doing it, and in fact your estimation of the normal amount might be wildly inaccurate both in terms of the locality and in terms of the companies. You can analyse these factors forever and get a different answer each time.

It's a negotiation, you aim high and give yourself enough margin to negotiate with. There is no point in aiming low unless you're desperate.